# How to get text from string confined between two specific words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I get the whole HTML code from JSON using Ajax , The fetched string looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">        
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">         
        ..
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            ...
        </div>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <script></script>
        ..
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to get the whole code from the div with class container `<div class="container">` to this one `<div id="overlay"></div>`.

How to accomplish that so that I just get the html part I want from the `<body>` not the whole string?

Comment: It's not recommended, but you can stick that string in a `$()` and perform a find on it.  Edit: the not recommended part being sticking an entire DOM in a `$()`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @Musa , I don't have the file , It's a string from a response from ajax request using `$.getJSON`

Comment: `'<div class="container">' + html_string.split('<div class="container">')[1].split('<div id="overlay"></div>')[0] + '<div id="overlay"></div>'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
    (function(window, document){ 
        // `res` is the ajax response string 
        const res = `<!DOCTYPE html> 
        <html lang="en"> 
        <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        </head> 
        <body> 
        <div class="container"> 
        stuff from container. 
        </div> 
        <div id="overlay"></div> 
        </body> 
        </html>`; 
        const wrapper = document.createElement("div"); 
        wrapper.innerHTML = res; 
        let str = ''; 
        str+=wrapper.querySelector("div.container").outerHTML; 
        str+=wrapper.querySelector("div#overlay").outerHTML; 
        alert(str); 
    })(window, document); 
</script>
```

Comment: You're using the DOM API on a String of HTML, not on HTML. Therefore your answer is incomplete.

Comment: Elaborate on incomplete, please. I could barely decipher what the user was trying to accomplish. I guess I nailed exactly what he was trying to do.

Comment: The OP posted HTML. That HTML is a string (retrieved via Ajax). He wants to manipulate that string of HTML so that the contents of the `.container` are placed in the `#overlay` element. `document.querySelector('#overlay')` will - obviously - not work on a string. Your answer is incomplete because it requires the use of a document object model in order to use the methods with which you attempted to solve the question. Incidentally, if you have trouble understanding a question, leave a comment on the question asking for clarification.

Comment: See my updated answer (look for the "to make David happy" section). @DavidThomas

Comment: Uh, thanks? But while I appreciate the attempt at completion, in that section you've left out the part that moves the content; and in neither section are you removing the content from its original location.

Comment: If it's just a string, I don't need to remove it, do I? I was under the impression (after you elaborated) that it's just a response(-text). So it'll get gc'd, within the next tick(s).

Comment: @walialu , I think you didn't get what I mean , I get that string from Ajax , I want to extract part from it which starts from '<div class="container">' to  `<div id="overlay"></div>`

Comment: So, IDK, but if my updated answer is still not sufficient, I'm outta here ;) because then I still don't fully grokh what you're trying to achieve :) /cc @jack

Comment: @walialu , I'm getting a full page html code and I want to extract a specific part from this html code returned from ajax `$.getJSON`

Comment: @walialu , So instead of having the whole string from `<!DOCTYPE html>` to `</html>` , I want to get the part from `<div class="container">` to `<div id="overlay"></div>`

Comment: @jack Do you only want the `<div id="overlay"></div>` with the contents of `<div class="container">` returned? So e.g.:

`<div class="container">Awesome content..</div>` would return `<div id="overlay">Awesome contant...</div>`

I'm still confused about where the `<div id="overlay">` is coming from? is it part of the HTML you fetched via ajax or is on the page that made the ajax request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167112/discussion-between-walialu-and-jack).